# WPF Context Menu Click event works in one place, not in another

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, contextmenu, eventhandler

I have the following XAML that produces a ListBox where each item contains another ListBox inside an Expander, and I have defined `PageContextMenu` as the context menu for the top level list and `FrameContextMenu` for the lower level list.

The problem: Both are displayed correctly, but click events are only working on the top level context menu and not the lower level context menu.  For example, clicking on `Delete Selected` in `PageContextMenu` correctly invokes the associated handler, but clicking on `Delete Selected Frame(s)` in `FrameContextMenu` does NOT fire the associated handler.  I'm not seeing any indication of an error, and even if I put a breakpoint in `ContextDeleteFrames_Click` it doesn't get hit.  It's as if there's no handler associated with that menu entry at all.

I've looked at a number of other questions relating to context menus not working, but none seemed applicable.  Is there some problem with the two list boxes being nested?

### XAML:

```xml
<ListBox Name="PageListBox" ItemsSource="{Binding CurrentPack.Pages}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" SelectionMode="Extended">
<ListBox.Resources>
    <ContextMenu x:Key="PageContextMenu">
        <MenuItem Header="_Add" Name="ContextAddAddPage"/>
        <MenuItem Header="_Edit" Name="ContextEditPage"/>
        <MenuItem Header="_Delete Selected" Name="ContextDeletePage" Click="ContextDeletePage_Click"/>
    </ContextMenu>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
        <Setter Property="ContextMenu" Value="{StaticResource PageContextMenu}"/>
        <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
    </Style>
</ListBox.Resources>
<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate >
        <Border  BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="White" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
            <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                <Label Content="{Binding PresentationName}"/>
                <Expander  VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                    <Expander.Header>
                        <Label Content="{Binding FrameStatusText}"/>
                    </Expander.Header>
                    <ListBox Name="FrameListBox" ItemsSource="{Binding Frames}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" SelectionMode="Extended">
                        <ListBox.Resources>
                            <ContextMenu x:Key="FrameContextMenu">
                                <MenuItem Header="_Add Frame" Name="ContextAddFrame"/>
                                <MenuItem Header="_Edit Frame" Name="ContextEditFrame"/>
                                <MenuItem Header="_Delete Selected Frame(s)" Name="ContextDeleteFrames" Click="ContextDeleteFrames_Click"/>
                                <MenuItem Header="Show _Preview" Name="ContextShowPreview" Click="ContextShowPreview_Click"/>
                            </ContextMenu>
                            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                                <Setter Property="ContextMenu" Value="{StaticResource FrameContextMenu}"/>
                                <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                            </Style>
                        </ListBox.Resources>
                        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Label Content="{Binding PresentationName}"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    </ListBox>
                </Expander>
            </StackPanel>
        </Border>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

### Code Behind:

```cs
    private void ContextDeletePage_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    { //this works
        Workspace.Content.DeleteSelectedPages();
    }

    private void ContextDeleteFrames_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    { //this doesn't!
        Workspace.Content.DeleteSelectedFrames();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use events in a `DataTemplate`. They won't work.

Either move your second context menu from the `DataTemplate`'s resources into the `PageListBox` resources like this:

```
<ListBox Name="PageListBox">
    <ListBox.Resources>
        <!-- ... other resources... -->

        <ContextMenu x:Key="FrameContextMenu">
            <MenuItem Header="_Add Frame" Name="ContextAddFrame"/>
            <MenuItem Header="_Edit Frame" Name="ContextEditFrame"/>
            <MenuItem Header="_Delete Selected Frame(s)" Click="ContextDeleteFrames_Click"/>
            <MenuItem Header="Show _Preview" Name="ContextShowPreview" Click="ContextShowPreview_Click"/>
        </ContextMenu>
    </ListBox.Resources>
</ListBox>
```

...or use commands instead of events:

```
<MenuItem Header="_Delete Selected Frame(s)" Command="{Binding DeleteFrameCommand}"/>
```

where `DeleteFrameCommand` is a property of type `ICommand` or `RoutedCommand`.

If you want to use commands, you should be aware that a context menu is not in the visual tree of its `PlacementTarget`, so you'll have to use some helpers to make the bindings work (a binding proxy or `PlacementTarget.Tag` property etc.)

Comment: Thanks.  Is it generally the case that all resource type things should be contained in the resources of the top level control rather than in an element of the data template?  Or is this a specific limitation of things that create events?